# More than one page advancing on mouse scroll using fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, fullpage.js

I'm using [fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) to build a site with VirtualBox to test on IE 10/11. I'm noticing that when I scroll the window advances two pages down, rather than just one. Has anyone else experience this, or is it maybe that I am using VB? I'm able to replicate the bug on the full page website.

Live example: http://realbadrabbits.com/projects/fullpage/index.html

Here's my initialization:

`$(document).on('ready', function() {
    // Fullpage settings
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        anchors: ['landing', 'navigation', 'page1', 'page2', 'page3'],
        css3: true,
        navigation: true,
        navigationPosition: 'left',
        navigationTooltips: ['Landing', 'Navigation', 'Page 1', 'Page 2', 'Page 3'],
        scrollOverflow: true,
        loopBottom: true
    });
});`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I'm noticing that when I scroll the window advances two pages down,
>   rather than just one.

It sounds like you are initializing fullPage.js multiple times! 
Make sure you only initiate it once!

A link to your URL will help to find the issue. Or at least, a reproduction on jsfiddle or codepen.

### Update:

The question has been answered in [the github issues forum](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/2695). Probably due to the use of Virtual Box.

Comment: Interesting, I was getting that error in IE sometimes. By initializing do you mean I'm calling $('#fullpage').fullpage({ etc }); twice? I'll get a version up. Thanks @Alvaro!

Comment: Yeah, that's the initialization. Make sure you only call that once in all your site / files .

Comment: As mentioned I'm able to replicate this on the fullpage website, which seems strange?

Comment: The question has been answered in the [github issues forum](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/2695). Probably due to the use of Virtual Box.